# How to enable Quotes for test classes?

Tags: quote, quotelineitem

I'm making a managed package for SalesForce AppExchange and use Quote and QuoteLineItem objects in the code. Creating and updating those objects is done in a generic way without hardcoding those Objects' API names.
That's done to avoid creating dependencies when assembling the package because we assume, that the app can be installed in orgs where Quotes are not enabled (Generally installing a package with Quote API name mentioned in the code is not possible for an org with Quotes disabled because that object simply doesn't exist in the client org).

How can I write test classes in apex for testing creating/updating Quotes and QuoteLineItems in a generic way without hardcoding the Quote API name in the tests? So I somehow need to verify that the Quote/QuoteLineItems are inserted in test for org where Quotes are not enabled.